# Email validation with Javascript; every email appears to be invalid

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble validating email addresses with JS. Here is my code:

```
var regEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/i;
var result = regEmail.test('username');
alert(result);
```

So no matter what kind of email address I type, it always shows "false". I copied the regex expression from somewhere on stackoverflow, but I think it should actuylly work...

EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submitBtn').click(function() {

        //Überprüfe ob der Benutzername leer ist
        var username = $('#username').val();
        if (username == ""){
            alert ("User name cannot be empty!");
        }

        //Email validation

        var regEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/i;
        var result = regEmail.test('username@example.com');
        alert(result);

        });
    });
```

Comment: This returns true: [`var result = regEmail.test('username@example.com');`](http://jsfiddle.net/pjLkncpw/).

Comment: Like almost every other regex for email validation, that one disallows perfectly valid addresses. Validation beyond "is there at least one character either side of an `@`?" is usually a waste of time. Send to the address, have the user verify they got the message.

Comment: I just tested it... it shows false...

Comment: @alina: *"I just tested it... it shows false"* No, it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/ygd1y1at/

Comment: then what the hell is wrong with my code... I just tested it (I made a form) and it shows "false" all the time... I must be doing something wrong, I just dont know what

Comment: @alina, post complete code, obviously - problem is somewhere else...

Comment: You are probably using wrong selector for email field. Re-check your HTML.... or, post your form html here.... http://jsfiddle.net/nkk1k084/ it works fine....

Comment: @nevermind thanks, I'll do that :)

Answer (score -2):

The regex validates against `A-to-z|A-to-Z|0-9` followed by `@` symbol and `A-to-z|A-to-Z|0-9` followed by `dot` and two to four letter of `A-to-z|A-to-Z|0-9`

You're passing only a single string without matching the regex rules.

Comment: missing `_` and `.` and `+` and `-`